# If $\dfrac{bx-ay}{cy-az}=\dfrac{cx-az}{by-ax}=\dfrac{z+y}{x+z}$, then the ratio is equal to $\dfrac{x}{y}$, unless $b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\dfrac{bx-ay}{cy-az}=\dfrac{cx-az}{by-ax}=\dfrac{z+y}{x+z}$, then will each of these fractions be equal to $\dfrac{x}{y}$, unless $b+c=0$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{bx-ay}{cy-az}=\dfrac{cx-az}{by-ax}=\dfrac{z+y}{x+z}=k$

$$bx-ay=(cy-az)k$$

$$cx-az=(by-ax)k $$

$$z+y=(x+z)k$$

Then I don't know how to proceed. If I set $k=\dfrac{x}{y}$ then the equations become really messy, so it doesn't seem like this is the way. Besides the question asks to show the ratios equal $\dfrac{x}{y}$, not assume it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=0$, it gives

$$\dfrac{bx}{cy}=\dfrac{cx}{by}=\dfrac{z+y}{x+z}\Rightarrow b^2=c^2$$

Since $b+c\neq0$, we get $b=c$, done.

If $a\neq0$

> $$bx-ay=(cy-az)k\tag{1}$$
> $$cx-az=(by-ax)k\tag{2} $$
> $$z+y=(x+z)k\tag{3}$$

$(1)+(2)+a\cdot(3)$, we get

$$(b+c)x=(b+c)yk$$

Since $b+c\neq0$, we get $x=yk$, hence $k=\frac xy$, done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I follow you to $b^2=c^2$. But then how do you know $b+c\neq0$? And why do I need to know that before just squaring both sides and getting $b=c$? For the second part, how do you know to operate doing $(1)+(2)+a\cdot(3)$? And why do you also know here $b+c\neq0$?

Comment: you said "unless" $b+c=0$

Comment: Why is it necessary to set $a=0$ in the beginning and finding out $b=c$? Can't we just skip to doing the three equations? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can, this is just my personal habit to discuss special cases separately.

Comment: I understand in $(b+c)x=(b+c)yk$ that $b+c\neq0$ is a necessary condition (Otherwise it will be $0=0$. How does $b+c\neq0$ affect $b^2=c^2$? I don't understand this part because I would just square root it without thinking about $b+c\neq0$. Thanks.

Comment: $b^2=c^2\Longleftrightarrow (b+c)(b-c)=0$